# Width: 100% not working in portrait on Featured Image in Custom Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a fullscreen, mobile friendly theme which displays Featured Images of posts as big as they can be with no cropping. This means in landscape displaying them with `height:100%; width:auto;`, but in portrait displaying them `width:100%; height:auto`. (As in many iOS apps.)

Trouble is, I'm having a real bugger of a time getting this to work in WordPress. When I developed the theme as a static HTML test site, it all worked completely fine. But for some reason, when I converted the site to a theme, it started ignoring the width:100% in portrait.

I know it's not the media query itself that is broken/being ignored, because the nav menu which is within the same portrait media query works fine.

Initially I thought WordPress' inline Image sizes had overridden my responsive ones (which would make sense, cascade-wise) but that doesn't seem to be the case as the image displays fine with height:100% in landscape viewports. In portrait, it seems to be listening to the height:auto command.

*It's literally just the `width: 100%;` command that is being ignored.*

I've also added in `max-width: 100%` just for good measure, and tried it with !important in various places. No effect.

Here's the code so you can see it's not a silly missing semicolon.

```
#content img {
width:100%;
max-width:100% !important;
height:auto;
}
```

I have also validated my CSS and nothing seems to be wrong there.

And here's the HTML

```
<div  id="content">                 
               <div title="Click to flip" class="sponsor">

                    <div class="sponsorFlip">
                        <?php 
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { // check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it.
                              the_post_thumbnail();
                            } 
                        ?>

                    </div>

                    <div class="sponsorData" style="display:none">
                    <?php 
                        if( class_exists( 'kdMultipleFeaturedImages' ) ) {
                        kd_mfi_the_featured_image( 'featured-image-2', 'post' );
                        }
                    ?>      
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div><!-- End div #content -->
```

& here's some screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Please, oh please, somebody save me from my portrait problem.

Comment: Seriously? Without any HTML code, how do you expect us to understand? And which theme are you using? Any preview? Any screenshots?

Comment: Not sure how HTML or screenshots will help but I will edit the post and add it in now.

Comment: Oh and the theme is made from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've basically solved this now in that I've got it working how I wanted it to - However I don't really understand why it now works.

I've deleted the Portrait Media Query so the default setting is portrait, and then left the landscape stuff in there conditionally. Is there something wrong with putting both a portrait and landscape media query in the same document? I can't seem to find anything about it on the web, and I'm sure I only had this problem when I converted the site to a wordpress template.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this, may be...

Give this in the `<head />` part.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't change anything :(